# Перевод приложения при входе

Tags: java, android

В зависимости настроек телефона, а именно в зависимости от проставленного в нём языка, при входе в приложения изменять язык приложения. Для каждого строкового ресурса были созданы файлы `strings.xml` для двух языков, ну не в этом суть думаю.

Нашёл нечто подобное:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Мол данный метод можно реализовать в `onResume` главного активити моего приложения. Но что-то не работает. Как можно иначе решить проблему?

Примечание: тут, как я понимаю, по умолчанию идёт установка русского языка, а мне нужно чтоб выбирался русский к примеру, если только языка установленного на телефоне, не существует в приложении.

Comment: Покажите, какие у Вас есть строковые файлы и скажите, какой язык установлен в ОС.

Comment: А вы перевели сами строки на тот язык, который добавили?

Comment: `чтоб выбирался русский к примеру, если только языка установленного на телефоне, не существует в приложении` – лучше бы английский выбирать в таком случае. Ну или русский только если геолокация определяет, что мы в СНГ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а разве выбирается по геолокации, не от языковых настроек телефона?

Comment: @RostislavDugin strings.xml в values-Индекс языка. в ОС стоит английский.

Comment: @Evgeniy конечно да)

Comment: @NickVolynkin как возможно определить по геолокации?

Comment: @Morozov так раз таки меня это и больше волнует, так как в стране могут говорить и на нескольких языках, поэтому приоритетней будет выбирать от языковых настроек.

Comment: @Morozov наверняка только от настроек зависит. Про геолокацию — пальцем в небо, я плохо разбираюсь в мобильной разработке. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реагируя на "волнения" автора вопроса, предложу следующий вариант:

В первую очередь создать BaseActivity, от которой унаследуете свою главную активность. В самой же активности стоит прописать нечто следующее:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Locale mCurrentLocale;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mCurrentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Locale locale = getLocale(this);

    if (!locale.equals(mCurrentLocale)) {

        mCurrentLocale = locale;
        recreate();
    }
}

public static Locale getLocale(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String lang = sharedPreferences.getString("language", "en");
    switch (lang) {
        case "English":
            lang = "en";
            break;
        case "Russian":
            lang = "ru";
            break;
    }
    return new Locale(lang);
}
}
```

Здесь в свитч можете накидать сколько угодно Вам языков, если конечно же у вас уже существует переводы на эти языки в строковых ресурсах.Также как Вы наверное успели заметить, новый язык я сохраняю в SharedPreferences. 
Далее стоит создать расширение для приложения:

```
 public class YourApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setLocale();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setLocale();
}

private void setLocale() {

    final Resources resources = getResources();
    final Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    final Locale locale = getLocale(this);
    if (!configuration.locale.equals(locale)) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
    }
}
}
```

Также не забудьте класс YourApp объявить в AndroidManifest'e:

```
 android:name=".YourApp"
```